# sorting an array in the same line as instantiation/initialization

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, initialization

If given an array of `ints`:

```
int[] age = new int [] {32, 25, 56, 56, 12, 20, 22, 19, 54, 22};
```

Is there a way to sort(lowest-highest) in the same line as instantiation/initialization, so that the elements of age would be: `12, 19, 20, 22...`?

Comment: Given that this is a fixed array, just sort them by hand. Otherwise, what issue is there with having another line for sorting?

Comment: Why? Sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: I'm just wondering, was trying to see if it could be done.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a real problem, it is asking if something is possible, not how to fix a problem.

Comment: I don't really find it off-topic.  "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development" - This may be a solution for someone else who wonders the same things and does want to implement this feature for whatever reason.

Comment: You don't need to write statements in different lines. You could add `Arrays.sort(age);` to the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not same line.

But you can do:

```
public static int[] sort(int[] a) {
   Arrays.sort(a);
   return a;
}
// ...
int[] age = sort(new int[] {32, 25, 56, 56, 12, 20, 22, 19, 54, 22});
```

Comment: It is not superfluous, it is precisely the point of my ``sort`` method: not to be void and return the array so that it can be used as a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

### One line is not an important goal:

Technically:

```
int[] age = new int [] {32, 25, 56, 56, 12, 20, 22, 19, 54, 22}; Arrays.sort(age);
```

Is one line but I do not think that is what you want.

It is implied that you want it `inline` which is a questionable goal, especially in Java.

### Inline vs OneLine

This *works*, but is extremely more convoluted than two lines and more inefficient as well because it has to box everything.

```
@Nonnull public static <T> T[] sort(@Nonnull final T[] array) { Arrays.sort(array); return array; }
```

And here is how you would call it:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sort(new Integer[]{32, 25, 56, 56, 12, 20, 22, 19, 54, 22})));
}
```

Outputs:

```
[12, 19, 20, 22, 22, 25, 32, 54, 56, 56]
```

> I do not see the usefulness of this simple experience tells you that
>   one line is never a valid goal.

#### Compare the byte code to:

```
    final int[] ints = new int[]{32, 25, 56, 56, 12, 20, 22, 19, 54, 22};
    Arrays.sort(ints);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
```

Then try and justify *saving* one line of code.